# jQuery if() works bad asking for empty ajax response

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, null, stock

I have a form which I load in parts depending on the users selection.

When the users select a date, I search for the qtty of available stock on that date (this are seats on a train travel).

I Have 3 `IF()` sentences

- First, I ask if the db response doesn't return any row (so the travel for that date haven't been created so I must create it in that moment for the costumer to reserve)
- Second, I ask if the response is a number (I only return a number, sorry if I didn't specified that before) AND if it's bigger than zero. so I update the available qtty. So the costumer can't over buy non-existing seat.
- Third and last, if the others fails and the qtty is zero, I just send the customer a message indicating that, the travel is full for that date, he/she must choose a different date to travel.

The code I have is this:

```
$.post(url,function(data){
        //********************
        //data = parseInt(data);
        alert("muestra: "+data+".");
            //3 opciones
        //si viene vacia la respuesta, es por que no encontro, reservas  o sea que nadie a reservado para la fecha solicitada
        //     lo que sigue es crear la reserva de todas formas, luego re-consultar por los valores y traer la cantidad total //podria mejorar
        //si viene con 0 es por que no existe disponibilidad para el viaje en esa fecha, tendra que intentar cambiando categoria (vagon) o fecha
        //si un numero >=1 hay disponibilidad y se crean los sliders que le permiten seleccionar la cantidad de asientos para reservar
        //TODO: cambiar al switch ....
        if(data=="false" || data==false){
        //if(data=='NaN'){
            $("#info-disponibilidad").html("No existen reservas previas, sera el primero en reservar para esta fecha. Asientos Disponibles: ");
            $("#info-disponibilidad").css("color","green");
            var myRandom=parseInt(Math.random()*99999999);  // tecnica cache buster
            //url = 'asientos-disponibilidad.php?categoria='+$('#categoria option:selected').val()+'&fecha_reserva='+$('#fecha_reserva').val()+'&rand=' + myRandom;
            url = 'crear_reservas.php?viaje='+$('#viajes option:selected').val()+'categoria='+$('#categoria option:selected').val()+'&fecha_reserva='+dateText+'&rand=' + myRandom;
            $.post(url,function(data2){
                //algo algo con la respuesta... ...
                alert("1er: "+data2+".");
            });
        }

        if(!isNaN(data) && data!=0){
        //if(!isNaN(data) && data!=0){
            alert("2do: "+data);
            //este se puede aprender facilmente al buscar el ejemplo en Jquery Ui slider
            $("#info-disponibilidad").html("Existen, "+data+" asientos Disponibles");
            $("#info-disponibilidad").css("color","green");
            //este se puede aprender facilmente al buscar el ejemplo en Jquery Ui slider
            $( "#slider-adultos" ).slider({
            //range: "min",
            min: 1,
            max: data,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#adultos" ).val(ui.value );
                $("#adultos").trigger("change");
            },
            stop: function(event, ui) { 
                $("#total-box").effect("highlight", {}, 2000);  
                //var max = parseInt($("#adultos").val());//usar esta variable en lugar de value (por si algo falla)
                manejoreservas(ui.value,"ninos", data);
            }
            });
            $("#slider-ninos").slider({
            //range: "min",
            min: 0,
            max: data,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#ninos" ).val(ui.value );
                $( "#ninos" ).trigger("change");
            },
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                $("#total-box").effect("highlight", {}, 2000);
                //$("#slider-ninos").slider( "option", "max", max );
                //var max = parseInt($("#ninos").val());//
                manejoreservas(ui.value,"adultos", data);
            }
            });
        }
        else//(!isNaN(data) && data==0  && data!=false)
        {   // && data!=false
            alert("3ro: "+data+" no disponibilidad");
            $("#info-disponibilidad").html("No existen asientos Disponibles");
            $("#info-disponibilidad").css("color","red");
        }
        });
```

and the php code is this:

```
<?php
//busca cual es la cantidad de asientos disponibles en una reserva si es que esta existe...
include('conn.php');
if (!$con)
  {
    die('Fallo conexion a la Base de datos: ' . mysql_error());
  }else{
  $categoria = $_GET['categoria'];
  //$fecha = $_POST['fecha_reserva'];
  $fecha = $_GET['fecha_reserva'];

  $sql_cant ="SELECT restante FROM reservas WHERE fecha_reserva = '".$fecha."' AND categorias_idcategorias = ".$categoria."";

  mysql_select_db("mvargas", $con);

  $result = mysql_query($sql_cant);
  $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
  //echo $sql_cant;
  if($num_rows < 0){
    echo "";
  }else{


    //echo "<b>".$num_rows."</b>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $foo = $row['restante'];
      $j++;
    }  
    //
    //var_dump($foo);
    echo $foo;
  }
}
?>
```

The last thing I have achieved, is that everything is working, but it enters the first `IF` displaying a message that the user will be first reservation in that date (create the travel) then it enters the third `IF` (else in the code shown) erasing the first message, and setting the message for the zero qtty, flashing awkwardly both messages in the screen for the user confusion.

Sorry if it's too long... here is the page for you to see: http://www.micontrol.cl/~mvargas/wordpress/wp-transatacama/reservas-rapidas/form-reservas.php

Comment: the first `if` can be made as, `if(!data){`

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you correctly, change the 2nd if to an else if...

```
....
....
            alert("1er: "+data2+".");
        });
    } else if(!isNaN(data) && data!=0){
    //if(!isNaN(data) && data!=0){
        alert("2do: "+data);
....
....
```

It will then only run the 2nd if statement if the first one is not true.

Comment: i think you meant "only run the second or third if the first one is not true", sounds like what he wants to me.

Comment: Good point - I did mean that, yeah, but since the 3rd is not an if statement, but actually an else, I didn't think it needed saying.

Comment: both of you guys are right, first of all I have 3 IF wanting to enter just one of em, then I change to that If else, cuz it was entering the first (so it creates a DB register for the new travel)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in the case you are referring to the `data` variable is returning 0 or blank.  In javascript the statement `0 == false` evaluates to true.  You need to use what is called a strict comparison such as `0 === false` which evaluates to false.

So update your code like this:

```
if(data=="false" || data===false){
```

it is a good idea to use strict comparison operators at all times unless you have a specific reason not to.  They are `===` and `!==`

Note that the following statements evaluate to true

```
(false == 0); // true  
(false == ""); // true
```

Comment: anyone have any idea, of what php returns (in my php code above).
it seems to be echoing something more than just an empty string,
even thought var_dump() writes NULL

Comment: Knowing what your PHP code returns when you echo an undefined variable is important (you might want to set it to something in the case of finding no rows since echoing an undefined variable may be an error and may result in an unintended return value), but the the other piece is what is actually in the data variable that is returned to your javascript in the $post callback.  Can you use a console.log or an alert to see what the value of data is?